# Attach javadoc to library's .jar in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, javadoc

I have a Java Class Library developed on Netbeans 12. Now I would like to attach the Javadoc to the .jar generated, so users when adding the library's .jar  file to their projects can make use of the Javadoc.

I am new on Netbeans and I haven't found a way to accomplish this after googling for a while.

Any idea?

Comment: The only standard method to do this I know of, is publishing as maven artifact.

Comment: You can publish the Javadocs as a separate .jar file, then this jar file can be attached to the library definition in NetBeans